# I want to turn currenttime and duration into a percentage

Tags: javascript, html, video

Hey so I want to monitor the progress of a video playing by percentage so when a user watching 25, 50 and 75% in sends an alert. This is what I have so far.

```
var Currenttime1 = document.getElementById('video').attr('currenttime');
var Duration1 = document.getElementById('video').attr('duration');
console.log(Currenttime1);
console.log(Duration1);


function percenttime(){


                var timemonitored = Duration1/Currenttime1 *100;

                var alertsSent = 0;
                if(timemonitored > 25 && alertsSent == 0)
                {
                console.log(timemonitored);
                    alert("player has reached 25%");
                    alertsSent++;
                }
                else if(timemonitored > 50 && alertsSent == 1)
                {
                    alert("player has reached 50%");
                    alertsSent++;
                }
                else if(timemonitored > 75 && alertsSent == 2)
                {
                    alert("player has reached 75%");
                    alertsSent++;

                }
            }
```

Is there something I'm missing? I put in console.log to see what is in Duration1, Currenttime1 and timemonitored but it's not populating with the values. Here is the fiddle link. http://jsfiddle.net/Ypczm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. check your syntax, your variables sometimes are capital and sometimes not
2. use only jquery functions like .attr() when you have loaded jquery...
3. you are defining the function but never call it. when do you expect this function to run?

one way could be to create an interval function which fires every 1000ms and get the current playtime with jquery.

Edit: working JS with jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var vid = $('#video'),
        check,
        reached25 = false,
        reached50 = false,
        reached75 = false;

    vid.bind("play", function(event) {
        var duration = vid.get(0).duration;

        check = setInterval(function() {
                var current = vid.get(0).currentTime,
                    perc = (current / duration * 100).toFixed(2);


                if (Math.floor(perc) >= 25 &&! reached25) {
                    console.log("25% reached");
                    reached25 = true;
                }
                console.log(perc);
        }, 1000);
    });

    vid.bind("ended pause", function(event) {
        clearInterval(check);
    });

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypczm/2/)

Comment: Out of interest is there a way to get current time in javascript or is jquery just an easier way to go?

Comment: as of everything, everything you can do in jquery is just javascript, which means of course. doing stuff in jquery is absolutely possible in pure js aswell, but most often not as easy :)

Comment: I didn't think you'd do it for me but thanks very much works great!

Answer (score -1):

You have multiple syntax errors:

```
console.log(Currenttime1)
                         ^--missing semi-colons (and on other lines as well)

console.log(duration1)
            ^---not capitalized
```

If you'd bothered looking at your browser's Javascript console (e.g. shift-ctrl-J in firefox), you'd have seen the JS syntax errors, which have completely KILLED the entire code block.

...

and now I see you stealth edited away the `D` v.s. `d` error, but no matter... the semicolon business still stands.

Comment: Sorry for the little mistakes but it still doesn't fix the overall problem.

Comment: -1 This is not an answer. You should have written it as a comment.

Comment: Ah ok Alex thanks I'll remove it and try another way.

Comment: @Zoltan.Tamasi: how is this not an answer? If someone asks why their car isn't starting, and you point out that the motor is missing, you would downvote that too?

Comment: I would vote it up if it was a comment. Comments are good for observations, but I think you should only post an answer if you have an exhaustive one that completely solves the answer and is a good candidate to be the accepted one.

Comment: @MarcB sure, but you only pointed out that the snowchains are still on in May. Poor form, sure, but not the cause of the issue. (The snowchains here being semicolons, which are definitely not the issue.)